# Which are the most effective methods of optimizing a drupal 7 site?

Tags: 7

Is there any module which would help in optimizing drupal 7 site ?
The drupal site (used for **bank** both for transactions as well and for non transactions as well without using drupal commerce) becomes very slow in terms of loading pages or any nodes..
So which are different ways in which we can optimize the Drupal 7 site to work smoothly and efficiently?

Answer (score 2):

[Boost](https://drupal.org/project/boost) module is the best option for performance issues, even it will works great in shared hosting. It will not hit the server for every request, instead it cache the pages and deliver them and Boost will cache & gzip compress html, xml, ajax, css, & javascript. Boosts cache expiration logic is very advanced; it's fairly simple to have different cache lifetimes for different parts of your site.

> Boost provides static page caching for Drupal enabling a very
>   significant performance and scalability boost for sites that receive
>   mostly anonymous traffic. For shared hosting this is your best option
>   in terms of improving performance.

Comment: But, its not suitable for authenticated user.

Comment: @Jayendra Kainthola : can u please elaborate why so that I can get to know ?

Comment: @harshal, As it work mostly on anonymous traffic and if site has content which changes frequently like news site, community site, then I think it will not work properly. I have not worked on this module yet.

Comment: @harshal, you can check comparison list of module https://groups.drupal.org/node/21897 for caching.

Comment: @JayendraKainthola no, its not like new site for content change, it will only overwrite the changed content cache, I'm using this module for all my sites, works great.

Comment: @JayendraKainthola see the comparison list, performance wise boost and varnish is very high

Comment: @Bala, yes, its very high for performance wise. I am not saying that you are wrong. If you check the list, then its only recommended for anonymous user. I want to let OP know about this only. I have already given you +1 vote.

Comment: @JayendraKainthola, I agree what you are saying, definitely for eCommerce site (with authenticated users ) my choice would be other than boost. Since the OP not mentioned anything about the type of website, I suggest him boost, anyway thanks for sharing the info.

Comment: @Bala, yes. I know OP not mentioned anything for type of website, so I already given +1 vote for this.

Comment: pls check updated question.@Bala, @JayendraKainthola

Comment: @harshal do you have authenticated users ?

Comment: yes it will have authenticated users.